# Presto SQL - Two completely different tables to join parallel instead of vertical

Tags: sql, join, presto

I have two tables that with completely data set and headings.

I managed to join together but using the codes refer at below, but this is vertical combine.

```
QUERY = """
SELECT SUM(CAST(US.amount as DECIMAL(13,2))) filter (where type IN ('USA')) as "USA Net Amount" from da1.tb1 
UNION 
SELECT SUM(CAST(EU.amount as DECIMAL(13,2))) filter (where type IN ('EU')) as "EU Net Amount" from da2.tb2
"""
results = fetch_data(QUERY)
display(results)
results.to.csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

Below is my output, and the EU net amount output as second row.

| USA Net Amount |
| --- |
| 50.00 |
| 100.00 |

Something I want to achieve, the EUR net amount output as new second column.

| USA Net Amount | EU Net Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 50.00 | 100.00 |

Comment: Perhaps a `CROSS JOIN` instead?

Comment: Or just use a comma SELECT SUM(CAST(US.amount as DECIMAL(13,2))) filter (where type IN ('USA')) as "USA Net Amount" from da1.tb1 
,
SELECT SUM(CAST(EU.amount as DECIMAL(13,2))) filter (where type IN ('EU')) as "EU Net Amount" from da2.tb2

Comment: @jarlh - mismatched input for 'CROSS'

Comment: @Emanuele - this does not work neither

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1."USA Net Amount", t2."EU Net Amount"
FROM
    (SELECT SUM(CAST(US.amount as DECIMAL(13,2))) filter (where type IN ('USA')) as "USA Net Amount"
     from da1.tb1) t1
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(CAST(EU.amount as DECIMAL(13,2))) filter (where type IN ('EU')) as "EU Net Amount"
     from da2.tb2) t2
```

However, I don't know if this syntax is supported?

*Conforms to SQL-2016
The following feature outside SQL-2016 is used:
T612, Advanced OLAP operations
T611, Elementary OLAP operations
F591, Derived tables
F401, Extended joined table*

Comment: It must be a better/optimized way for the output as if there are more columns, above scripts seems very repetitive

Answer (score 0):

Add type column to the queries in UNION ALL(you need UNION ALL here, not UNION) to indicate country and use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(AMT) FILTER(WHERE type="USA") as "USA Net Amount", 
       max(AMT) FILTER(WHERE type="EU") as "EU Net Amount"
from      
(
    --aggregation in union ALL can be executed in parallel
    SELECT SUM(CAST(US.amount as DECIMAL(13,2)))  as Amt, type from da1.tb1 where type IN ('USA') group by type
    UNION ALL ---not UNION !
    SELECT SUM(CAST(EU.amount as DECIMAL(13,2)))  as Amt, type from da2.tb2 where type IN ('EU')  group by type
) as s
```

OR using single aggregation step after UNION ALL:

```
select sum(AMT) FILTER(WHERE type="USA") as "USA Net Amount", 
       sum(AMT) FILTER(WHERE type="EU") as "EU Net Amount"
from      
(
    SELECT CAST(US.amount as DECIMAL(13,2)) as Amt, type from da1.tb1 where type IN ('USA')
    UNION ALL ---not UNION !
    SELECT CAST(EU.amount as DECIMAL(13,2))  as Amt, type from da2.tb2 where type IN ('EU')
) as s
```

Comment: UNION ALL also only does the vertical output

Comment: @Alex UNION does DISTINCT. UNION ALL combines datasets into one, no distict applied. UNION = UNION ALL + DISTINCT. UNION ALL performs faster, in fully parallelized mode because it does no DISTINCT